# System.InvalidOperationException: An ItemsControl is inconsistent with its items source

Tags: c#, wpf

I am getting the following exception down below

Things to know:
-I have researched this exception and found that all the references to it involve people using threading ---- I am NOT USING THREADING, my app is plain vanilla single thread and linear.
-The suggested answers I have found say to use Dispatcher and BeginInvoke() methods.  Im not using those. and they are irrelevant to my code.
-Im using MVVM. according to the error this list of objects is throwing the error in my viewmodel

```
  private List<curve> curves{get;set;}
```

Is this a .net4.5 bug?  What could be causing this and how can I fix it?

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

--------------------------EXCEPTION/STACK TRACE----------------------

> System.InvalidOperationException: An ItemsControl is inconsistent
>   with its items source.
>         See the inner exception for more information. ---> System.Exception: Information for developers (use Text Visualizer to
>   read this):
>       This exception was thrown because the generator for control 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid Items.Count:0' with name '(unnamed)'
>   has received sequence of CollectionChanged events that do not agree
>   with the current state of the Items collection.  The following
>   differences were detected:
>         Accumulated count 0 is different from actual count 9.  [Accumulated count is (Count at last Reset + #Adds - #Removes since
>   last Reset).]
>
> One or more of the following sources may have raised the wrong events:
>        System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator
>         System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection
>          System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView
>           System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[AI.ClientHousingUtilities.Module.Models.curve,
>   AI.ClientHousingUtilities.Module, Version=1.24.0.20239,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] (The starred sources are
>   considered more likely to be the cause of the problem.)
>
> The most common causes are (a) changing the collection or its Count
>   without raising a corresponding event, and (b) raising an event with
>   an incorrect index or item parameter.
>
> The exception's stack trace describes how the inconsistencies were
>   detected, not how they occurred.  To get a more timely exception, set
>   the attached property 'PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel' on the
>   generator to value 'High' and rerun the scenario.  One way to do this
>   is to run a command similar to the following:
>   System.Diagnostics.PresentationTraceSources.SetTraceLevel(myItemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator,
>   System.Diagnostics.PresentationTraceLevel.High) from the Immediate
>   window.  This causes the detection logic to run after every
>   CollectionChanged event, so it will slow down the application.
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator.Verify()    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureChild(IItemContainerGenerator&
>   generator, IContainItemStorage& itemStorageProvider,
>   IContainItemStorage& parentItemStorageProvider, Object& parentItem,
>   Boolean& hasUniformOrAverageContainerSizeBeenSet, Double&
>   computedUniformOrAverageContainerSize, Double&
>   computedUniformOrAverageContainerPixelSize, Boolean&
>   computedAreContainersUniformlySized, Boolean&
>   hasAnyContainerSpanChanged, IList& items, Object& item, IList&
>   children, Int32& childIndex, Boolean& visualOrderChanged, Boolean&
>   isHorizontal, Size& childConstraint, Rect& viewport,
>   VirtualizationCacheLength& cacheSize, VirtualizationCacheLengthUnit&
>   cacheUnit, Boolean& foundFirstItemInViewport, Double&
>   firstItemInViewportOffset, Size& stackPixelSize, Size&
>   stackPixelSizeInViewport, Size& stackPixelSizeInCacheBeforeViewport,
>   Size& stackPixelSizeInCacheAfterViewport, Size& stackLogicalSize,
>   Size& stackLogicalSizeInViewport, Size&
>   stackLogicalSizeInCacheBeforeViewport, Size&
>   stackLogicalSizeInCacheAfterViewport, Boolean&
>   mustDisableVirtualization, Boolean isBeforeFirstItem, Boolean
>   isAfterFirstItem, Boolean isAfterLastItem, Boolean skipActualMeasure,
>   Boolean skipGeneration, Boolean&
>   hasBringIntoViewContainerBeenMeasured, Boolean&
>   hasVirtualizingChildren)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl(Size
>   constraint, Nullable`1& lastPageSafeOffset, List`1&
>   previouslyMeasuredOffsets, Nullable`1& lastPagePixelSize, Boolean
>   remeasure)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverride(Size
>   constraint)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridRowsPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size
>   constraint)    at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size
>   availableSize)    at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size
>   availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.UpdateLayout()    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.<>c__DisplayClass94_0.b__0()
>   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source,
>   Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)

Comment: You should be using an `ObservableCollection` if you are doing data-binding.

Comment: I have had that suggested to me and I suppose I can try that.  However I use Lists that are bound on other grids and I do it a lot and i have never seen this error.

Answer (score 1):

This error can occur if the source list was modified somewhere and the data used in the View no longer matches the data in the list. Yes, that can easily happen in threads but doesn't require a thread to cause it.

The problem stems mostly from the fact that the List does not support INotifyPropertyChanged so the UI doesn't stay updated with the changes. You could define your `curve` class to support INotifyPropertyChanged or use a class that already handles it, like ObservableCollection.

Comment: You are right.  The observablecollection did do the trick.  Thank you!